# Django management command unable to return dict

Tags: python, django

I've written a management command:

```
class Command(BaseCommand):

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument("member_id", nargs="+", type=str)

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        return other_function(options["member_id"][0])
```

that calls an imported function:

```
def other_function(identifier):
    return {"foo": "bar"}
```

When I call the other function from the shell it works correctly; however, when using the management command I get:

```
  File "/Volumes/www/bin/../apps/manage.py", line 61, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Volumes/www/src/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 354, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Volumes/www/src/django/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 346, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Volumes/www/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 394, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Volumes/www/lib/python2.7/site-packages/raven/contrib/django/management/__init__.py", line 41, in new_execute
    return original_func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Volumes/www/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 454, in execute
    self.stdout.write(output)
  File "/Volumes/www/src/django/django/core/management/base.py", line 111, in write
    if ending and not msg.endswith(ending):
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'endswith'
```

Can management commands only return strings?  The documentation doesn't seem to say so but if I change the `handle` function to `return "foo"` it works.  But that seems silly.

Comment: the doc does say it has to return an unicode string: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.handle

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. It must return a string, if it returns anything. "It may return a Unicode string which will be printed to stdout "
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: I saw that but interpreted the "may" differently.  Thanks!